# I can't seem to understand the meaning of this one line of code (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've read a bunch of tutorials and posts but I just got more and more confused. In Laymen's terms(extremely simple and explicit terms), what does the code below do?? what is replace(/ /g, '-') ? what is req.params.item?

```
return todo.item.replace(/ /g, '-') !== req.params.item;
```

And for more context, the entire code is shown below.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var data = [{item: 'get milk'}, {item: 'walk dog'}, {item: 'kick 
some coding ass'}];
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/todo', function(req, res){
    res.render('todo', {todos: data});

});


app.post('/todo', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    data.push(req.body);
    res.json(data);
});


app.delete('/todo/:item', function(req, res){
    data = data.filter(function(todo){
        return todo.item.replace(/ /g, '-') !== req.params.item;
    });
    res.json(data);
});

};
```

Comment: `todo.item.replace(' ', '-')` replaces one space with a hyphen. `todo.item.replace(/ /g, '-')` replaces all the spaces with hyphens.

Comment: Wow. thanks for the great tip. but what's the purpose of turning spaces into hyphens?

Comment: I guess it expects a `DELETE /todo/get-milk` request, which is kind of bad API design.

Comment: hmm I'm not really understanding what     `DELETE /todo/get-milk` request really is. Are you saying that this code is trying to equalize "some item" to "some-item"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns all spaces in the `todo.item` string into dashes, compares the replaced string to `req.params.item`, and returns `true` if they are different. For example, if `todo.item` is `foo bar`, and `req.params.item` is `foo-bar`, it will return `false`.

What the filter does

```
data = data.filter(function(todo){
    return todo.item.replace(/ /g, '-') !== req.params.item;
});
```

is it turns `data` into an array which contains *only* items which do not pass that test.

```js
let data = [
  { item: 'foo bar' },
  { item: 'bar baz' },
  { item: 'baz buzz' },
];
const req = { params: { item: 'bar-baz' }};

data = data.filter(function(todo){
    return todo.item.replace(/ /g, '-') !== req.params.item;
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: so... what would the entire code in the app.delete() block achieve?

Comment: It means that when `/todo/:item` is pinged with a request to delete the associated resource, all matches for the corresponding `item` param will be removed from the `data` array on the server, and the server will respond with the new filtered array.

Comment: and where do the values of params come from? I never made an object "params" so I'm not sure how params got values all of a sudden...

Comment: also... hypothetically, if it's `data = data.filter(true);` , would it delete every value in the data array?